# Probability of child1 given child2 =?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

- Let A, B and C be 3 random variables with binary outcomes $\{0,1\}$ defined by the probabilistic graph model below.
- If B is observed as $(B=1)$ & A and C are not observed.
- What is the probability that C = 1 given B = 1?
- We have $P(B|A)$, $P(C|A)$ and $P(A)$

I am searching for the formula only.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand the picture.  What is the relation between $A,B,C$?  What do we know about the distributions of $A,B,C$?

Comment: @lulu imagine A is a topic and B and C are words. B and C depend on A, but in general A doesn't depend on B and C. now if you observe B, you can't say the same anymore.
Is that clearer?

Comment: That's pretty vague.  What, exactly, do we know about each of the variables $A,B,C$?  What, exactly, do we know about their dependence on one another?

Comment: @lulu I don't see why it is vague. A doesn't depend on B and C, but C depends on A and B depends on A. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes.  Dependence is a symmetric relation.  If $B$ depends on $A$ then $A$ depends on $B$.  In your problem statement, I have no idea what information is given. Do we, say, know the joint distribution function for $(A,B,C)$?

Comment: Yes indeed, if B is observed then A depends on B and thus B depends on A and B.
in the problem we have the conditional probabilities $P(B|A)$ and $P(C|A)$ as well as $P(A)$. Sorry I will add this info to the post

Comment: You'll need joint distribution information as well.

Comment: I don't have it.

Comment: Then you can't solve the problem.  Suppose each variable is a coin toss (prob $\frac 12$ for both outcomes) and that neither $B$ not $C$ depend on $A$ at all.  In scenario I, assume that $B=C$, in Scenario II assume that $C=1-B$.  Easy to see that your data matches in both scenarios but $P(C=1\,|\,B=1)$ is $1$ for the first scenario and $0$ for the second.

Comment: @lulu, as I read things, the equation $P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)$ means that the occurrence of $B$ *requires* the occurence of $A$ and depends on nothing else, and likewise for $C$ from the equation $P(C)=P(C|A)P(A)$. From that I get $P(C|B)=P(C|A)$ because conditioning on $B$ implies $A$ has occurred, at which point $C$ occurs with probability $P(C|A)$. Or am I missing something? (Ah, I see the OP has removed these equations in an edit.)

Comment: @BarryCipra  Yeah, it's really unclear to me what the given information is meant to be.  The most obvious thing, I'd have thought, is to say the joint distribution is known.  Given that, we could, of course, compute everything.  As it is, I feel like we're just guessing what the secret assumptions are.

Comment: I am sorry I can't be more obvious. I don't know what to add

Comment: @lalaland:

The issue is that we need more information on the conditional distribution $P(B \cap C|A)$ which could be obtained if we ideally had the joint distribution of $(A,B,C)$. We can write $$P(C=1|B=1)=\frac{P(B=1,C=1)}{P(B=1)}$$ Using the total law of probability this equals $$\frac{P(B=1,C=1|A=0)P(A=0)+P(B=1,C=1|A=1)P(A=1)}{P(B=1|A=0)P(A=0)+P(B=1|A=1)P(A=1)}$$
We can compute every term in the denominator and we can also compute $P(A=0)$ and $P(A=1)$. However, $P(B=1,C=1|A=0)$ and $P(B=1,C=1|A=1)$ can take on any value.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewHolder I will try to build on this

Comment: If you assume we have conditional independence, then we can say $$P(B=1,C=1|A=0)=P(B=1|A=0)P(C=1|A=0)$$ $$P(B=1,C=1|A=1)=P(B=1|A=1)P(C=1|A=1)$$ Can you assume conditional independence? If so then you can compute every term here.

Comment: Please try to edit your [old posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3842981/321264) to add details instead of asking again.

Comment: @MatthewHolder  YES exactly given A, B B and C are independent. Thank you so much

Comment: Great. Just make sure this is a valid assumption because otherwise you need more information on $P(B\cap C|A)$.

Answer (score 1):

**I assume the random variables are chosen uniformly?**
If that's the case:

---

"I am searching for the formula only."

Then i guess this is the formula you're after?:

∀ x∈U: P(x) = 1/|U|

the above formula(called the Uniform Distribution)
Means that,

- for all/every(∀) element x in(∈) Universe(U):
- the Probability of x is 1 ÷ the size of U (denoted |U|)

---

A try at the answer itself: Correct me if I'm wrong:
Isn't the probability that C = 1 given B=1,
1/3 or,  0,3?

---

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for answering but Iam not sure to understand. let say you have a document with 2 possible topics.  and the appearance of words depends on the topic. in general the words chosen depend on the topic, but once you see a word even if you don't know what the topic is, you can say something about it and therefore you can say something about the other word

Comment: I am not quite sure I follow; I can explain the formula, of course :)

Comment: I will give it a try to understand your example; although I can't guarantee It's a good understanding .  1 document.   2 topics(which we don't know about)   The frequency of words are dependent on the topic. But once you observe a word, (the topic is still unknown) - you can say something about the other word(the next word)? Have I understood you correctly?  If yes;  Yeah I agree, I mean a word like "computer" can be in very many different topics. And if I would predict the next word, I guess it would be something releated to a or more computer(s). (Maybe "someone turned the"*computer*" on)?

Comment: Note; I am quite unsure in the example, so excuse me if my understanding is crazy.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamMartens. I appreciate your help. Matthew holder wrote something interesting in the comment section on my post above. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah sure, I just want to help :) have a good day, and everyone reading this too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation seems to be conflicted about whether $A,B,C$ are binary random variables or events. I'm going to go with events because that makes writing things easier, but of course, these are equivalent.

Also, I am assuming $B$ and $C$ are conditionally independent given $A$, which you've implied but not actually said outright.

In that case, we can figure out $\Pr[A \cap B \cap C]$ as $\Pr[A] \cdot \Pr[B \mid A] \cdot \Pr[C \mid A]$. (Normally, this would have $\Pr[C \mid A \cap B]$, but we are assuming conditional independence here.) We can also figure out $\Pr[A^c \cap B \cap C]$ as $\Pr[A^c] \cdot \Pr[B \mid A^c] \cdot \Pr[C \mid A^c]$.

Finally, $\Pr[B \cap C] = \Pr[A \cap B \cap C] + \Pr[A^c \cap B \cap C]$, and $\Pr[C \mid B] = \frac{\Pr[B \cap C]}{\Pr[B]}$.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the help but I not sure you can assume conditional independence because A is unobserved

Comment: Conditional independence has nothing to do with whether $A$ is observed or not. It is simply a matter of whether $\Pr[B \cap C \mid A] = \Pr[B \mid A] \cdot \Pr[C \mid A]$ holds. (And the same thing with $A^c$ in place of $A$.)

Comment: If this does not hold, then you do not have enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: @MishaLavrov:  Hello, I'm not quite sure I follow this correctly, is it stated that B and C are independently-A? Sorry if this may be a dumb question.

Comment: @WilliamMartens What do you mean by "independently-A"?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I mean, is B and C dependent of A? But I think I understood it before, but thanks